# Magento - Invalid block type

Tags: magento-1.9, php, blocks, exception

i open this topic for a problem that is generate in exception.log

```
2016-03-25T15:25:07+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Blog_Block_Blog' in /var/www/vhosts/higift.it/httpdocs/upgrade/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/higift.it/httpdocs/upgrade/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 /var/www/vhosts/higift.it/httpdocs/upgrade/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('blog/blog', Array)
#2 /var/www/vhosts/higift.it/httpdocs/upgrade/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('blog/blog', 'blog.custom')
#3 /var/www/vhosts/higift.it/httpdocs/upgrade/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('blog/blog', 'blog.custom')
#4 /var/www/vhosts/higift.it/httpdocs/upgrade/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /var/www/vhosts/higift.it/httpdocs/upgrade/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /var/www/vhosts/higift.it/httpdocs/upgrade/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#7 /var/www/vhosts/higift.it/httpdocs/upgrade/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(113): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 /var/www/vhosts/higift.it/httpdocs/upgrade/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'toronto_homepag...')
#9 /var/www/vhosts/higift.it/httpdocs/upgrade/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'toronto_homepag...')
#10 /var/www/vhosts/higift.it/httpdocs/upgrade/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#11 /var/www/vhosts/higift.it/httpdocs/upgrade/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#12 /var/www/vhosts/higift.it/httpdocs/upgrade/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#13 /var/www/vhosts/higift.it/httpdocs/upgrade/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#14 /var/www/vhosts/higift.it/httpdocs/upgrade/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 /var/www/vhosts/higift.it/httpdocs/upgrade/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#16 {main}
```

I tried to delete the block of blog but without success. Where it could be the problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to find this block in content of the cms page with id `toronto_homepage` and remove it (in the admin panel).

Or try to find it directly in mysql:

```
SELECT * FROM `cms_page` WHERE `content` LIKE '%blog/blog%' OR `layout_update_xml` LIKE '%blog/blog%' OR `custom_layout_update_xml` LIKE '%blog/blog%'
```

In addition try to search 'blog/blog' in layouts.

Comment: @Gabriel91 You are welcome =)