# How to solve this extension.log error?

Tags: magento-1.9, error, blocks

From some days ago, I have this error at `exception.log`. 
It occurs each time I open any page, so it's repeating all the time. 
How can I solve this? I'm new in Magento.

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Etheme_Coolbabyconfig_Block_Navigation' in app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('coolbabyconfig/...', Array)
#2 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('coolbabyconfig/...', 'topMenu')
#3 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('coolbabyconfig/...', 'topMenu')
#4 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#7 app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(113): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_PageController), '26')
#9 app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/PageController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_PageController), '26')
#10 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_PageController->viewAction()
#11 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#12 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#13 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#14 app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 index.php(123): Mage::run('', 'store')
#16 {main}
```

OR:

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Etheme_Coolbabyconfig_Block_Navigation' in app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('coolbabyconfig/...', Array)
#2 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('coolbabyconfig/...', 'topMenu')
#3 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('coolbabyconfig/...', 'topMenu')
#4 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#7 app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/View.php(73): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/View.php(144): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View->initProductLayout(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), Object(Mage_Catalog_ProductController))
#9 app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/ProductController.php(132): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View->prepareAndRender(7, Object(Mage_Catalog_ProductController), Object(Varien_Object))
#10 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Catalog_ProductController->viewAction()
#11 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#12 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#13 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#14 app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 index.php(123): Mage::run('', 'store')
#16 {main}
```

Comment: The class `Etheme_Coolbabyconfig_Block_Navigation` cannot be found. Did you try to uninstall a theme?

Comment: It is for the theme I'm using. It has been solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for `coolbabyconfig/navigation` in your project layout files and comment out or delete them. In case you don’t use the Etheme_Coolbabyconfig extension at all, just switch it off (open `app/etc/modules/Etheme_Coolbabyconfig.xml` and set `<active>false</active>`).

**EDIT**

Here a [solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108030/magento-invalid-block-type/108046#108046) for the static blocks was added from the backend:

> Try to find this block in content of the cms pages and remove it (in
>   the admin panel).
>
> Or try to find it directly in mysql:

```
SELECT * FROM `cms_page` WHERE `content` LIKE '%coolbabyconfig/navigation%' OR `layout_update_xml` LIKE '%coolbabyconfig/navigation%' OR `custom_layout_update_xml` LIKE '%coolbabyconfig/navigation%'
```

Comment: I commented in my local.xml :
<block type="coolbabyconfig/navigation" ... it seems that it was loading some static blocks that don't exist, maybe from a previous version of the theme. 
Now I'm not getting the exception! Thanks!

Comment: @Pau Always welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

most probably there is a block declared in your layout file without a type.
Something like this:

```
<block name="anyblock-name"></block>
```

Missing block type

```
<block type="block-type-here" name="anyblock-name"></block>
```

Comment: It was not the case of that exception. But I had another exception and was solved adding the type to the block! thanks!