# error on log file

Tags: magento-1.9

Please can anyone tell me how to remove these errors from exception.log file ?
My frontend is working fine but, I don't know why these errors are occurring when I click on checkout

```
2016-04-14T10:49:35+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Tco_Block_Iframe' in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\hotdeals4less.com\httpdocs\app\Mage.php:594
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Inetpub\vhosts\hotdeals4less.com\httpdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 C:\Inetpub\vhosts\hotdeals4less.com\httpdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('tco/iframe', Array)
#2 C:\Inetpub\vhosts\hotdeals4less.com\httpdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('tco/iframe', 'tco.iframe')
#3 C:\Inetpub\vhosts\hotdeals4less.com\httpdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('tco/iframe', 'tco.iframe')
#4 C:\Inetpub\vhosts\hotdeals4less.com\httpdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 C:\Inetpub\vhosts\hotdeals4less.com\httpdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(206): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 C:\Inetpub\vhosts\hotdeals4less.com\httpdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#7 C:\Inetpub\vhosts\hotdeals4less.com\httpdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#8 C:\Inetpub\vhosts\hotdeals4less.com\httpdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#9 C:\Inetpub\vhosts\hotdeals4less.com\httpdocs\app\code\local\Magestore\Onestepcheckout\controllers\IndexController.php(63): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout()
#10 C:\Inetpub\vhosts\hotdeals4less.com\httpdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): Magestore_Onestepcheckout_IndexController->indexAction()
#11 C:\Inetpub\vhosts\hotdeals4less.com\httpdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#12 C:\Inetpub\vhosts\hotdeals4less.com\httpdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#13 C:\Inetpub\vhosts\hotdeals4less.com\httpdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#14 C:\Inetpub\vhosts\hotdeals4less.com\httpdocs\app\Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 C:\Inetpub\vhosts\hotdeals4less.com\httpdocs\index.php(97): Mage::run('', 'store')
#16 {main}
2016-04-14T10:49:35+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Wirecard_Checkout_Page_Block_Seamless_Script' in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\hotdeals4less.com\httpdocs\app\Mage.php:594
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Inetpub\vhosts\hotdeals4less.com\httpdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 C:\Inetpub\vhosts\hotdeals4less.com\httpdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('wirecard_checko...', Array)
#2 C:\Inetpub\vhosts\hotdeals4less.com\httpdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('wirecard_checko...', 'wirecard_checko...')
#3 C:\Inetpub\vhosts\hotdeals4less.com\httpdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('wirecard_checko...', 'wirecard_checko...')
#4 C:\Inetpub\vhosts\hotdeals4less.com\httpdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 C:\Inetpub\vhosts\hotdeals4less.com\httpdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
```

Comment: See here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4588/how-to-diagnose-invalid-block-type-error

Answer (score 1):

Search for `tco/iframe` in your project layout files and comment out or delete them.

Here a [solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108030/magento-invalid-block-type/108046#108046) for the static blocks was added from the backend:

> Try to find this block in content of the cms pages and remove it (in
>   the admin panel).
>
> Or try to find it directly in mysql:

```
SELECT * FROM `cms_page` WHERE `content` LIKE '%tco/iframe%' OR `layout_update_xml` LIKE '%tco/iframe%' OR `custom_layout_update_xml` LIKE '%tco/iframe%'
```

Comment: Hello, basicaaly i am using onestep checkout extension and in that extension Tco/iframe and Wirecard Checkout is used, and i don't know much about this issue, if any other solution related my issue then please let me know thank you

Comment: @ShreyaMahajan It seems that the block name has changed in the config.xml file. Could you, please, add its’ code to our query?

Comment: @ShreyaMahajan I mean the congfig.xml files of this modules :)  (from `app/code/{codePull}/Vendor/Module/etc/config.xml`)

Answer (score 0):

Two modules are causing the problem:

- The first error seems to be related to this extension: https://github.com/craigchristenson/magento-2checkout (you probably deleted it but you keep the related code in your layout files, look for `tco.iframe` in your layout files and remove the reference if you deleted the module)
- The second error is related to this extension: https://github.com/netzkollektiv/wirecard-checkout-magento and it's exactly the same problem as the first one, extension got deleted by related code is still present in the layout files, look for `wirecard_checkout_page` and it's the same process as above.